# How to create a custom rule for eslint and react

Tags: reactjs, cypress, eslint, eslint-plugin-react

I'm trying to add data-cy required in all my components, how I make this rule using eslint?
I'm using:

```
eslint-plugin-react
eslint-config-prettier
eslint
prettier
```

I have a component like this:

```
<MyButton propExample="" />
```

without data-cy, I want to data-cy get required in all my componentes
Example:

```
<MyButton propExample="" data-cy="hello" />
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.